# How can i create a while loop to display the lowest integer in my list?

Tags: while-loop

```
import random
nums = list()
def main():
    for count in range(7):
    number = random.randint(20, 80)
    nums.append(str(number))
    print(str(nums))
    while line in nums != '':
    print('The lowest value is', min(nums))
```

> > > main()
> > >       ['21', '39', '26', '33', '42', '35', '44']

I am required to use a while loop to display the integers in my list. I have to display the lowest in the list and the highest....etc. I just cannot figure out how to use a while loop to do this. Am I missing a variable? I'm not looking for the answer to my whole assignment, I just need help figuring out this while loop I understand how to do everything else once I get in the while loop, I just don't know how to construct it. Any help would be great and highly appreciated, just for the while loop. I'm new to Python and I've been working on this for 2 days straight.

Comment: Think of it kinda like this: While there are more things in the list, keep going. While going, check the next number in the list and see if it is higher than the highest one you've seen so far (same for smallest). You just need a variable to represent the largest and smallest numbers.